# Convert code format into CHtml::link Yii

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, onclick, yii-chtml

How can I convert the text TbButton bootstrap into CHtml::link in Yii?
below is the TbButton bootstrap code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Data Protection Policy - Must Read for Consultant',
    'type'=>'primary', // '', 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'addContactBtn','onclick'=>'js:(function(){
        $("#pdpaModal").modal({"show":true});
        return false;    
})();')));
```

I need to convert the code above into CHtml:

```
CHtml::link("Change Status", "#", array("onClick"=>"(function(){
   $("#pdpaModal").modal({"show":true});
   return false;    
})();"))
```

However, I get an error on the onClick part. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape double quote within double quote.

Either:

```
CHtml::link("Change Status", "#", array("onClick"=>"(function(){
   $(\"#pdpaModal\").modal({\"show\":true});
   return false;    
})();"));
```

or

```
CHtml::link("Change Status", "#", array("onClick"=>'(function(){
   $("#pdpaModal").modal({"show":true});
   return false;    
})();'));
```

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you very much. It works on the first option. :)